# How to save CheckBox value in SQL Server database in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, checkbox

I'm working on a Windows forms app, I created a room form which contains room name, size, and LAB.

The table in the database contains columns `RoomName` (`varchar`), `Size` (`int`), and `LAB` (`bit`).

This is the `ADD_ROOM` stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ADD_ROOM]
    @NAME_ROOM VARCHAR(50),
    @SIZE INT,
    @LAB BIT
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[ROOM] ([NAME_ROOM], [SIZE], [LAB])
    VALUES (@NAME_ROOM, @SIZE, @LAB)
```

Here is `ADD_ROOM.cs`:

```
class CLS_ADD_ROOM
{
        public void ADD_ROOM(string NAME_ROOM,int SIZE,Boolean LAB)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.Open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@NAME_ROOM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = NAME_ROOM;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@SIZE", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[1].Value = SIZE;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@LAB", SqlDbType.Bit);
            param[2].Value = LAB;

            DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_ROOM", param);
            DAL.Close();
        }

        public void UPDATE_ROOM(string ID_ROOM, string NAME_ROOM, int SIZE, bool LAB)
        {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.Open();

            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4]; 
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@ID_ROOM", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[0].Value = ID_ROOM; 

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@NAME_ROOM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50); 
            param[1].Value = NAME_ROOM; 

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@SIZE", SqlDbType.Int); 
            param[2].Value = SIZE; 

            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@LAB", SqlDbType.Bit); 
            param[3].Value = LAB; 

            DAL.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE_ROOM", param); 
            DAL.Close();
        }
```

And the code behind button `ADD Room` in ADD ROOM FORM

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ROOM.ADD_ROOM(TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text), Convert.ToBoolean(CHECK_LAB.CheckState));

    MessageBox.Show(" The Room has been added successfully", "ADD PROCEDURE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ROOM_VIEW.GET_ALL_ROOMS();
}
```

And the error is

> Input string was not in a correct format

Comment: Can you add all Exception's stack Trace?

Comment: http://im84.gulfup.com/wFq8fH.jpg

Comment: http://im84.gulfup.com/wFq8fH.jpg     @Fabio

Comment: Is TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text no longer than 50 symbols? Is TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text numeric?

Comment: TXT_ROOM_NAME is a textbox receive a string from user & TXT_ROOM_SIZE is a tectbox too which receive an integer from user. @26071986

Comment: @AnasAl-shami Yes, I understood. But is TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text length less than 50 symbols? In SP you await only 50 symbols, no more. So if the string is longer, you will have problems

Comment: @26071986 No it's 7 symbols maximum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your C# code, you should replace `Convert.ToBoolean(CHECK_LAB.CheckState)` with `CHECK_LAB.Checked` - that's the boolean with defines whether or not the checkbox is checked:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ROOM.ADD_ROOM(TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text, 
                  Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text), 
                  CHECK_LAB.Checked);

    MessageBox.Show(" The Room has been added successfully", "ADD PROCEDURE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ROOM_VIEW.GET_ALL_ROOMS();
}
```

The `CheckState` property is **not** a boolean property - it's one of three possible values:

- `CheckState.Checked`
- `CheckState.Unchecked`
- `CheckState.Indeterminate`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but this could be worth trying. In ADD_ROOM.cls:

```
param[2] = new SqlParameter("@LAB", SqlDbType.Bit);
param[2].Value = LAB ? 1 : 0;    // <---- CHANGE THIS LINE
```

Value of Boolean as parameter may be converted to something other than 0 or 1, which are expected by sql server.

Comment: I Filled the "Room" table using sql mangment studio and try The update function and it's worked ...the problem is how to save the initial value.. here is the code behind "update button"                       private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             ROOM.UPDATE_ROOM(TXT_ROOM_ID.Text,TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text,Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text),CHECK_LAB.Checked);  } @JoriO

Comment: There is no method `UPDATE_ROOM` in the code you gave us. @Anas Al-shami

Comment: Yeap..it's in ADD_ROOM.cls too:public void UPDATE_ROOM(string ID_ROOM,string NAME_ROOM,int SIZE,bool LAB)
{ DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL=new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
 DAL.Open();
 SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[4];
 param[0] =new SqlParameter("@ID_ROOM", SqlDbType.Int);
 param[0].Value =ID_ROOM;
 param[0] = new SqlParameter("@NAME_ROOM",SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
 param[0].Value =NAME_ROOM;
 param[1] = new SqlParameter("@SIZE",SqlDbType.Int);
 param[1].Value =SIZE;
 param[2] = new SqlParameter("@LAB",SqlDbType.Bit);
 param[2].Value =LAB;
 DAL.ExecuteCommand("UPDATE_ROOM", param); DAL.Close();}

Comment: @AnasAl-shami Room ID and Room Name go with the same index in params array, so you declare 4 values, but give only 3.

Comment: My answer is still the same. In UPDATE_ROOM.cls: `param[2].Value = LAB ? 1 : 0;`

Comment: @AnasAl-shami Perhaps you could edit the code in the question yourself? Now there is an additional parameter appeared, and you overwrite it yourself. It is very difficult to help you if you keep  making changes to your code but don't tell us what you have changed.

Comment: @26071986 yeap bro it's wrong..i fixed it thank you :) ..but still error in add_room :(

Comment: @JoriO yeap you are right .. I'm trying to fix error using ur suggestions but still not work ..

Answer (score 0):

**Thank you so much Guys .. the problem is solved :)**

**I changed this instruction in ADD_ROOM.cls :**

```
 class CLS_ADD_ROOM
    {
        public void ADD_ROOM(string NAME_ROOM,int SIZE,int LAB)// <=== Change bool to int 
   {
            DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
            DAL.Open();
            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];

            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@NAME_ROOM", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[0].Value = NAME_ROOM;

            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@SIZE", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[1].Value = SIZE;

            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@LAB", SqlDbType.Bit); //<=== keep it .bit
            param[2].Value = LAB ;


            DAL.ExecuteCommand("ADD_ROOM", param);
            DAL.Close();
            }
```

**And add this condition in ADD_ROOM Form :**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {               

if (CHECK_LAB.Checked)
{

ROOM.ADD_ROOM(TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text,int.Parse(TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text),Convert.ToInt32(1));

}
    else
{

   ROOM.ADD_ROOM(TXT_ROOM_NAME.Text, Convert.ToInt32(TXT_ROOM_SIZE.Text), Convert.ToInt32(0));              }
```